# Newbie confused about brackets

Tags: android

I'm writing my first app, I'm new to programming...this program is a work in progress, but  I'd like to see how it looks so far, if I could only get it to compile! I have a problem with the brackets I think, every time I fix one error, another appears somewhere else...is there an easy way to spot missing brackets? Thanks!

```
package com.Jenko.votingapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button createNew = (Button)findViewById(R.id.newPoll);
        createNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick (View view) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent("com.Jenko.votingapp.CREATENEWPOLL"), 1);
                finish();
            }

            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
              if (requestCode ==1) {
                  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                      //something will eventually happen here...
                  }

                  Button seePrevious = (Button)findViewById(R.id.prevPoll);
                  seePrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick (View view) {
                          startActivityForResult(new Intent("com.Jenko.votingapp.SEEPREVIOUSPOLL"), 2);
                          finish();
                      }
                  });
              }
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what line does the compilation fail?

Comment: *"is there an easy way to spot missing brackets?"* - Yup. Indent your code properly, missing brackets are very obvious this way. Google a bit around, you will find some examples, e.g. [this](http://www.javaranch.com/styleLong.jsp#indent).

Answer (score 2):

It's really important to indent properly. Any missing brackets will be easily noticeable if your indents are correct. Here it is indented and fixed brackets/parens:

```
package com.Jenko.votingapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

        Button createNew = (Button)findViewById( R.id.newPoll );
        createNew.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick( View view ) {
                startActivityForResult( new Intent( "com.Jenko.votingapp.CREATENEWPOLL" ), 1 );
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data ) {
        if( requestCode == 1 ) {
            if( resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {// something will eventually happen here...}
                Button seePrevious = (Button)findViewById( R.id.prevPoll );
                seePrevious.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick( View view ) {
                        startActivityForResult( new Intent( "com.Jenko.votingapp.SEEPREVIOUSPOLL" ), 2 );
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have an IDE, a good habit to get into is to immediately add the closing bracket, brace, or parenthesis the moment you type the opening one.  You can fill in the rest once you have both.  You'll never add an orphan that way.

I'll second all those comments that say consistent style and layout of code helps here.

Answer (score 1):

Use an IDE (eclipse, IntelliJ, etc).  Too heavy weight for you?  How about emacs or vim editors?  Both of them have bracket matching features.  Programming editors are a dime a dozen out there.  Pick one, learn it, and get on with your regularly scheduled programming.

Answer (score 0):

most coding standards place the opening bracket directly after the statement or function and give the the closing bracket its own line as well like so

```
    function() {
        do stuff here
    }
```

or right after the statement or function on its own line with nothing else like so

```
    function()
    {
        do stuff here
    }
```

this makes spotting opening and closing brackets easier. your code above refactored to meet
these standards looks like this

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity { <-- missing closing bracket

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { <-- missing closing bracket
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Button createNew = (Button)findViewById(R.id.newPoll);
            createNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { <-- missing closing bracket
                public void onClick (View view) {
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent("com.Jenko.votingapp.CREATENEWPOLL"), 1);
                    finish();
                } //end onClick

                public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { <-- missing closing bracket
                    if (requestCode ==1) {
                        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                            //something will eventually happen here...
                        }//end if


                        Button seePrevious = (Button)findViewById(R.id.prevPoll);
                        seePrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick (View view) {
                                startActivityForResult(new Intent("com.Jenko.votingapp.SEEPREVIOUSPOLL"), 2);
                                finish();
                            } //end onClick

                        }); //end View.OnClickListener
                    } //end if
```

you are missing closing brackets for:

MainActivity
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
public void onActivityResult
createNew.setOnClickListener

and as already mentioned proper code indentation helps alot

Comment: You guys are legends, that makes so much more sense now...thanks everyone!